# How to create 2D array with specified row size without specifying columns size using Scanner in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

**Here is a java code**

```
    public class Demo { 
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
            Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("enter the no of rows");
            int n =sc.nextInt(); 
            ArrayList<Integer>[] al = new ArrayList[n]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            { 
                al[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
            } 
            System.out.println("enter the value");
            int val=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {   
                while(val!='\n')
                {
                    val=sc.nextInt();       
                    al[i].add(val);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
                  for (int j = 0; j < al[i].size(); j++) { 
                    System.out.print(al[i].get(j) + " "); 
                 } 
                System.out.println(); 
             } 
        } 
     }
```

*I was tried to achieved by using an array of ArrayList. But while taking input from the user leads infinity inputs*

Answer (score 0):

```
while(val!='\n')
```

`val` is an `int`, don't compare it with a newline *character*. Change it to:

```
while (val != -1)
```

And enter `-1` to stop.

If the user can enter -1 as a valid element, you can change `val` to a string, replace the `sc.nextInt()` call, and parse the input to an int. Make sure you compare strings using `.equals()` and not `==`.

---

ASCII value of new line feed ('\n') is 10. So if you choose to continue using your current code, you'll have to stop the loop by entering the value `10` (which will be weird, and also, 10 can't be added as a valid element).